# unable to access session from one method to another in codeigniter REST API

Tags: rest, api, codeigniter

I am trying to register a form using codeigniter rest api.i have two methods.The code works fine if i access the session within the same method. But i'm not able to access the session value in the second method.i have loaded session library in autoload.
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','email');

**1st method**

```
public function register_post() {
  $authUser = $this->authUser();
  $variable = $authUser['id'];
  $name = $this - > post("name");
  $address = $this - > post("address");
  $this - > session - > set_userdata('some_name', $variable);

  $register = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'address' => $address,
    'posted_by' => $this - > session - > userdata('some_name')

  );
  $this - > load - > model('ApiModel');
  $this - > ApiModel - > tips_insert($register);
}
```

**second method**

```
public function add_clinic_post() {
  $area = $this - > post("area");

  $location = $this - > post("location");

  $add = array(
    'area' => $clinic,
    'location' => $location,
    'user_id' => $this - > session - > userdata('some_name')

  );

  $this - > load - > model('ApiModel');
  $this - > ApiModel - > clinic_insert($add);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public function authUser()
    {
        $decodedData = array();

        $authorizationHeader = $this->input->get_request_header('Authorization');

        $token = '';

        if(preg_match('/Bearer\s(\S+)/', $authorizationHeader, $matches))
        {
            $token = $matches[1];
        }

        if($token)
        {
            $decodedData = JWT::decode($token, $this->config->item('jwt_secret'), $this->config->item('jwt_alg'));
        }
        else
        {
            return array();
        }

        if($decodedData)
        {
            return (array) $decodedData->data;
        }
        else
        {
            return array();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to do you get $authUser in first method?

Comment: include the authUser function above.it works fine and i can get id throgh the authUser() and i can use it in first function(register_post)